# How to add buttons to a main window by programmatically in Qt and change styles them by use css file?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I will add two buttons to the a dialog and I want to change style sheets of them by use css file:

[image]

I also define the buttons as follows that didn't work:

```
sendButton = new QPushButton();
sendButton->setVisible(true);
sendButton->setText("sendButton");
sendButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton#sendButton {\n"
                          "background-color: red;\n"
                          "border-style: outset;\n"
                          "border-width: 2px;\n"
                          "border-radius: 10px;\n"
                          "border-color: beige;\n"
                          "font: bold 14px;\n"
                          "min-width: 10em;\n"
                          "padding: 6px;\n"
                          "}\n"
                          "QPushButton#reciveButton {\n"
                          "background-color: green;\n"
                          "border-style: outset;\n"
                          "border-width: 2px;\n"
                          "border-radius: 10px;\n"
                          "border-color: beige;\n"
                          "font: bold 14px;\n"
                          "min-width: 10em;\n"
                          "padding: 6px;\n"
                          "}\n");


ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(sendButton);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the *ID Selector* `QPushButton#objectName`, be sure to also set the object name for your QPushButton, otherwise the selector will not work

```cpp
sendButton = new QPushButton();
sendButton->setVisible(true);
sendButton->setText("sendButton");

sendButton->setObjectName("sendButton"); /* Set the object name */

sendButton->setStyleSheet(...);
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: This method doesn't work when I defin the buttons as follows:
sendButton = new QPushButton();
    sendButton->setVisible(true);
    sendButton->setText("sendButton");
ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(sendButton);

Comment: I have edited my answer to match your use-case.  It shuld be OK now (maybe =)

Answer (score 1):

To add any widgets programmatically to a window (MainWindow, Dialog, ...) you have to do as follows:

1. Create an instance of your widgets
2. Create a layout (vertical, horizontal, or grid layout)
3. Add widgets to the layout
4. Set your window's layout

For example:

```
    //Step 1: create widgets
    QPushButton *sendbtn = new QPushButton("sendButton");
    sendbtn->setObjectName("mySendButton");
    QPushButton *receivebtn = new QPushButton("receiveButton");
    receivebtn->setObjectName("myReceiveButton");

    //Step 2: create a layout
    QHBoxLayout *hlayout = new QHBoxLayout;

    //Step 3: add widgets to the layout
    hlayout->addWidget(sendbtn);
    hlayout->addWidget(receivebtn);
    QWidget *w = new QWidget;
    w->setLayout(hlayout);
    setCentralWidget(w);


    setStyleSheet("QPushButton#mySendButton"
                                   "{"
                     "background-color: red;"
                     "border-style: outset;"
                     "border-width: 2px;"
                     "border-radius: 10px;"
                     "border-color: beige;"
                     "font: bold 14px;"
                     "min-width: 10em;"
                     "padding: 6px;"
                     "}"
                     "QPushButton#myReceiveButton"
                                   "{"
                     "background-color: green;"
                     "border-style: outset;"
                     "border-width: 2px;"
                     "border-radius: 10px;"
                     "border-color: beige;"
                     "font: bold 14px;"
                     "min-width: 10em;"
                     "padding: 6px;"
                     "}");
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: When you set a widget's stylesheet, once Qt reaches to that command line, if the stylesheet command is not valid (i.e., it's not a valid css style sheet), Qt will write the error in the ```Application output```. Please check that to see if your stylesheet is valid. I'm a little hesitant about ```font: bold 14px;```.

Comment: Because I'm reading this styles from a css file,the  ID selector must be clear.#sendButton

Comment: Ok @MohsenGhahremaniManesh. Please see my **Edit 1**. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Could you write down here the error or the warning message? I think there is some problem with the ```setLayout``` line. Because a ```MainWindow``` already has a layout and we are trying to replace it. Honestly , I don't have access to my laptop right now. I'll check it and reply after an hour.

Comment: @MohsenGhahremaniManesh I posted the final solution. That works fine on my machine. The problem is that before using an ID selector, we must set an object name for that object. Seet [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html) for more details. Please accept this answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Just one another thing. I considered the object names as ```mySendButton``` and ```myReceiveButton```. You may have to consider proper object names based on your CSS file.